# Python 'hide' methods with __

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Today I see that - python add `_$CLASSNAME$` to methods with name with `__`.

Simple example:

```
>>> class A:  
...     def a(self):  
...         self.b()  
...     def b(self):  
...         print('A.b')  
...           
>>> class B(A):  
...     def b(self):  
...         print('B.b')  
...           
>>> B().a()  
B.b
```

That work, but:

```
>>> class A:  
...     def a(self):  
...         self.__b()  
...     def __b(self):  
...         print('A.b')  
...           
>>> class B(A):  
...     def __b(self):  
...         print('B.b')  
...           
>>> B().a()  
A.b
```

Why? I don't know, so I dir'ed it. Here it is:

```
>>> print([fn for fn in dir(B) if fn[-2:] != '__'])
['_A__b', '_B__b', 'a']
```

Why python do that? Is there way to bypass that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's called name mangling and done to prevent accidental name collisions with parent and child classes. You cannot (and should not, a lot of perfectly fine code uses it) disable it. You can circumvent it, but you should not do that either (it's extremely ugly, you can avoid it, and when you need access to it you shouldn't permit name mangling in the first place). Just use a single underscore for private functions you want to use anywhere but immediately inside the class.

See the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) but ignore any reference to this denoting a "private" variable. That's not what it's used for unless you use `private` in the C++/Java/C#/... sense of `private` variables (as opposed to `protected` which are visible to child classes) being hidden from child classes. Even then it's a flawed analogy.

Comment: So it's more like protected - subclass can't use it.

Comment: @xiado In all languages I am aware of that feature a distinction between `private` and `protected`, `privated` is the one not accessible to subclasses and hence closer to this. Which language's sense of `protected` are you talking about?

Comment: Excuse me - I think about something other - You got rigth.

Answer (score 15):

While none of this is strictly enforced by python, the naming convention of a double underscore means "private", while a single underscore means "protected".

A double underscore is meant to protect subclasses from causing errors by using the same name. By namespacing them by class name, the defining class can be sure its variables will remain valid.

A single underscore means that subclasses are free to access and modify those same attributes, being shared with the super class.

Both forms **suggest** that any outside class should not be accessing these.

```
class A(object):

    __private = 'private'
    _protected = 'protected'

    def show(self):
        print self.__private 
        print self._protected

class B(A):
    __private = 'private 2'
    _protected = 'protected 2'

a = A()
a.show()
#private
#protected

b = B()
b.show()
#private
#protected 2
```

This example shows that even though class `B` defined a new `__private`, it does not affect the inherited `show` method, which still accesses the original superclass attribute. `_protected` is however modified and the superclass `show` method reflects this, because they are the same attribute.

Comment: just to note, `__private` isn't truely private, you can still access and operate on it via `i = B(); i._B__private`. I have a method to make things almost truely private (still has `__closure__` access) here: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/threads/510759/snippet-how-to-privatize-attributes-of-a-slots-class#post2229436

Comment: none of this is true. Python does not have private or protected methods, everything is public (by design)

Comment: @Alex,everything can still be accessed with enough reflection. But the fact is that there is a naming convention that it meant to imply intention by an api. If you, for instance, reach into members prefixed with underscore, linters can tell you that you are accessing protected members. And the fact that double underscore causes the python runtime to apply name mangling means there is a concept of private intention. But yes, still, you can shoot yourself in the foot if you want. Python will let you